# PHP foreach and reference

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have one `var_dump` before and one after to show.

Why (and when) is `$data->offers` modified as foreach just copy the value in the variable ?

I have this code :

```
<?php
data = new stdClass();
$data->offers = $this->getOffreChildren(27);
var_dump($data->offers);
foreach ($data->offers as $offre) {
    $offre->contracts = $this->getOffreChildren($offre->id);
    foreach ($offre->contracts as $contract) {
        $contract->count = 0;
        foreach ($adhesions as $adhesion) {
            if ($adhesion->id_type_contrat == $contract->id)
                $contract->count = $adhesion->nombre;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($data->offers); die;
```

First `var dump` :

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[260]
      public 'nom' => string 'lorem' (length=6)
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'code' => string 'lorem' (length=5)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[261]
      public 'nom' => string 'lorem.... ' (length=19)
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'code' => string 'lorem..... lorem' (length=13)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[262]
      public 'nom' => string 'lorem...lorem' (length=17)
      public 'id' => string '48' (length=2)
      public 'code' => string 'lorem...lorem' (length=16)
   ....
```

The second `var_dump` :

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[260]
      public 'nom' => string 'lorem' (length=6)
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'code' => string 'lorem' (length=5)
      public 'contracts' => 
        array (size=14)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[258]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[257]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[256]
              ...
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[261]
      public 'nom' => string 'lorem.... lorem' (length=19)
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'code' => string 'lorem..... lorem' (length=13)
      public 'contracts' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[270]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[269]
              ...
```

Comment: Scalar values are copies, but these values aren't scalars, they're object instances.... and object instances are treated as references to the actual instance

Comment: Maybe this post will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works

Comment: strange that not getting error, because `$adhesions` is no where defined.

Comment: can you put you json data here. so that we can test and tell what happen.thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Foreach` walks your array and in your case adds `contracts` property to it with the command

```
$offre->contracts = $this->getOffreChildren($offre->id);
```

it is not clear where `$adhesions` comes from but with

```
$contract->count = $adhesion->nombre;
```

you add another property to the already added `contracts` property.